# problems using meteor to view things on firefox

Tags: meteor

Hy guys, i'm studing the meteorjs and i got some problems to see the things on firefox. On google chrome, everythings gonna well and i can see everything without errors.

My code is:

/-->server/server.js

```
Meteor.publish('places', function () {
return Places.find();
});
```

/-->model.js
    Places = new Meteor.Collection('placesNew');

```
Places.allow({
  insert: function(){
    return false;
  },
  update: function(){
    return false;
  },
  remove: function(){
    return false;
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  createPlace: function(options){
    check(options, {name: NonEmptyString, latitude: NonEmptyString , longitude:NonEmptyString , color: NonEmptyString});
    return Places.insert({name:options.name, latitude: options.latitude, longitude: options.longitude, color: options.color});
  },

  removePlace: function(options){
    return Places.remove(options.id);
  }
});

var NonEmptyString = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, String);
  return x.length !== 0;
});
```

/-->services.js

```
var map;
renderize_map = function (places){
  var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.36865 , 8.539183),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

      };
     map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      places.forEach(function (place) {
        var pinColor = place.color.replace("#","");
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(place.latitude, place.longitude),
                  title: place.name,
                  icon: pinImage,
                  map: map
              });
    });
}
```

/-->client/places_list.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('places');

Template.places_list.places = function () {
  return Places.find({},{sort:{name: -1}});

}

Template.places_list.events({
  'click #add':function() {
      options ={};
      options.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      options.latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
      options.longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
      options.color = document.getElementById('color').value;
      Meteor.call('createPlace',options, function(error,place){
        if(error){
          console.log("Não Foi possível inserir");
        }

      });
      renderize_map(Places.find({},{sort:{name: 1}}));
  },
    'click .plc_remove': function(obj){
      options={};
      options.id=obj.toElement.attributes['data-ref'].value;

      Meteor.call('removePlace',options, function(error,place){
        if(error){
          console.log("Não Foi possível inserir");
        }

      });      
      renderize_map(Places.find({},{sort:{name: 1}}));
    }

});

Template.maps.rendered = function() {
    renderize_map(Places.find({},{sort:{name: 1}}));
  }
```

/-->client/places_list.css

```
/* CSS declarations go here */
#map-canvas{
  width:  500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

/-->client/places_list.html

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>TableList</h1>
    {{> places_list}}
    {{> maps}}
  </header>
</body>

<template name="places_list">
  <div class"place-list-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a place here" value="{{name}}" id="name"/><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a Latitude here" value="{{latitude}}" id="latitude"/><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a Longitude here " value="{{longitude}}" id="longitude"/><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a Color here " value="{{longitude}}" id="color"/>  
    <button id="add">Add point</button>

  </div>  
  <div class"place-list-container">
    <ul>
      {{#each places}}
      <li> {{ name}} | <a class="plc_remove" data-ref="{{_id}}" href="#">x</a> | </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

  </div>

</template>

<template name="maps">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</template>
```

The  errors are:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after function body
http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?a3d111217f95d5af907302198a85413d1acbaf05
Line 1766

TypeError: Package.livedata is undefined
http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?a3509c5f9f4ed6ded19eaac97c69c2a91d81df81
Line 28

TypeError: Package.livedata is undefined
http://localhost:3000/packages/global-imports.js?fbb54e05f02190869755c48bbc5e3bd9f17811b4
Line 7

ReferenceError: Template is not defined
http://localhost:3000/client/template.places_list.js?ee7af8e7be9b55207b7bef609fa51cb0e5f513a9
Line 1

TypeError: Meteor.subscribe is not a function
http://localhost:3000/client/places_list.js?6a2a131bfee6da3c6e08cee25711a90317cb4a4e
Line 1

TypeError: Meteor.Collection is not a constructor
http://localhost:3000/model.js?9eed9b90a309156348195efef61705bab5494768
Line 1


ReferenceError: Spark is not defined
http://localhost:3000/client/template.places_list.js?ee7af8e7be9b55207b7bef609fa51cb0e5f513a9
Line 1
```

Can anyone helpme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copy and pasted all your code into a project and it works for me on both Firefox (version 19.0.2 on OSX) and Chrome. Or at the very least it loads everything and I could add a location that would be visible as a name in the other browser, it didn't add a pin to the map.

The errors you are getting are pretty fundamental errors suggesting that some of the essential built-in packages aren't loading correctly. I don't see why this would only be an issue in one browser though. If you view source in your browser is the list of packages the same in both Chrome and Firefox?

As a suggestion I would try editing the packages file (.meteor/packages from your project root directory). Try removing all the packages which will obviously cause the app to stop working and adding the default ones again which are:

- standard-app-packages
- autopublish
- insecure
- preserve-inputs

Beyond that, do other meteor apps run ok in Firefox? If not look at what add-ons and settings you have. If it's just this app and other people can get it working in Firefox then all I can think of is remaking the project copying and pasting your files in.

Comment: Thanks!
I don't know why, but the problem is when i run on my machine..i deployed that to a server and it worked!